# given density function $f(x)$, find $f_Y(y)$

Tags: statistics

If $X$ be a random variable with density function given by $f(x)=3 x^{-4}$,for $x\geq 1$.Let $Y =\frac{1}{X}$ , find $f_Y(y)$.

Comment: i don't know how to find  F x(x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $F$ denote the CDF corresponding to the PDF $f$. Then

$$F_Y(y)=\Pr(Y\leq y)=\Pr(\tfrac1X\leq y)=\Pr(X\geq\tfrac1y)=1-\Pr(X<\tfrac1y)$$

Since $\Pr(X=\tfrac1y)=0$, we have shown that
$$F_Y(y)=1-F_X(\tfrac1y)$$
Can you take it from here?

**Addendum:** Here's how to proceed. Since $F_Y(y)=1-F_X(\frac1y)$, we have
$$f_Y(y) = \tfrac{d}{dy}\left(F_Y(y)\right)\tag{reln. of $f_Y$ to $F_Y$}$$
$$=\tfrac{d}{dy}\left(1-F_X(y^{-1})\right)\tag{reln. of $F_Y$ to $F_X$}$$
$$=0-(-y^{-2})f_X(y^{-1})\tag{chain rule}$$
$$=y^{-2}3(y^{-1})^{-4}\tag{defn. of $f_X$}$$
$$=3y^2$$
for $0<y\leq1$.

Comment: i already found your hints from books, but my problem is how to find F x(x).

Comment: $F_X$ is the CDF corresponding to $f_X$. One always has $F'_X=f_X$, and $F_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^xf_X(t)\; dt$. In your case (since $f_X(x)=0$ for $x<1$), $$F_X(x)=\int_1^x3t^{-4}\;dt$$ for $x>1$

Comment: integral f(x) = 3 x^{-4} from 1 to x. i got -x^-3  -1.FY(y) = 1 - Fx(1/y). Then i substitute 1/y to x . Then my answer is x^3. but my right answer is 3y^2. I don't know where i did wrong.

Comment: See my addendum. You probably didn't use the chain rule properly.